# Testing Component That Fetches Data With React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I have a component that does some very basic fetching of data. Once this data is fetched, users can interact and click on the items in a list. When an item is clicked, it is displayed at the top of the component with a description as the "active item".

I'd like to test the click functionality by making sure that an item can be set to active, and also removed from being active. However, I am not sure how to do this, since it relies on data from an API. Any ideas?

**Component Code**

```
interface Item {
  title: string;
  description: string;
}

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<Item[]>([]);
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState<Item | null>(null);

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get<Item[]>('http://localhost:3090/api/items');
      setItems(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleActiveItem = (item: Item) => {
    if (activeItem?.title === item.title) {
      setActiveItem(null);
    } else {
      setActiveItem(item);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {activeItem && (
        <div data-testid="active-item">
          <h1>{activeItem.title}</h1>
          <p>{activeItem.description}</p>
        </div>
      )}

      <ul>
        {items.map((item: Item) => (
          <li key={item.title} onClick={() => handleActiveItem(item)}>
            {item.title}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Test Code**

```
describe('Home', () => {
  it('matches snapshot', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<Home />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  render(<Home />);

  it('Initially there is no active item', () => {
    const activeItem = screen.queryByTestId('active-item');
    expect(activeItem).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('When an item is clicked in the list, it becomes the active item', () => {
    //
  });

  it('If there is an active item and it is clicked in the list, active item is emptied', () => {
    //
  });
});
```